# Выбор часового пояса с помощью select

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте! Есть сайт где администратор сам может указывать часовой пояс, как это показано на картинке. После этого на сайте отображается время в указанном часовом поясе и все операции(регистрация, оплата и т.д.) заносятся в базу в этом часовом поясе. Как это можно реализовать? Может есть готовые библиотеки? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну дак поищите в гугле "php вывести время в часовом поясе". Найдёте например вот это: https://myrusakov.ru/php-tz-time.html достаточно просто всё описано.

Comment: @Al Mr, может есть какие-то библиотеки, где есть все часовые пояса?

Answer (score 1):

> А можно как-то вывести список всех временных зон с помощью стандартных
>   функции php?

Да, можно.
[DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php) -- timezone_identifiers_list — Возвращает численно индексированный массив со всеми идентификаторами временных зон

```
<?php
$timezone_identifiers = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();
for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo "$timezone_identifiers[$i]\n";
}
?>
```

Результат:

```
Africa/Abidjan
Africa/Accra
Africa/Addis_Ababa
Africa/Algiers
Africa/Asmara
```

Сам список всех timezones [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/timezones.php).

У меня в проекте было такое "костыльное решение", может поможет:

```
// Определяем какое у клиента Московское время
        date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); // Устанавливаем часовой пояс по Гринвичу
        $time = time(); // Вот это значение отправляем в базу
        $time += 3 * 3600; // Добавляем 3 часа к времени по Гринвичу, чтобы привязывать пользователей к Московскому часовому поясу
        //$cur_hour = date('d-m-Y, H:i:s', $time);
        $cur_hour = date('H', $time); // получить значение Часы из Московского времени
```

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такой вариант. У вас есть выпадающий список, где администратор выбирает часовой пояс и он заносится в 
`date_default_timezone_set("ваше часовой пояс");` и сохраняется(допустим с помощью `file_get_contents` в отдельный файл), а потом просто подключается в нужный файлах с помощью `include`. И не надо возни с отдельным скриптовыми преобразованиями как в комментарии выше. Ведь точно не извество сразу, какой часовой пояс.

[Тут вы можете посмотреть поддерживаемые временные зоны для функции](http://php.net/manual/ru/timezones.php)

Comment: т.е. если я правильно вас понял, администратор выбирает часовой пояс, после этого часовой пояс заносится  в бд. Потом получаем значение из бд и вставляем в `date_default_timezone_set("часовой пояс из бд")`.  После чего по умолчание часовой пояс будет который мы выбрали, и все операции будут проходить уже под этим часовым поясом?

Comment: А можно как-то вывести список всех временных зон с помощью стандартных функции php?

Comment: БД для одной записи? Можно просто создать php  файл `timezone` и записать в него значение сразу после выбора. Или администратору надо часто менять зону? Если нет, то динамическая подгрузка не нужна. Насчет вывода, я не слышал таких функций, надо писать самому с помощью `<section>`.